# SQL is there a way to sort multiple time columns into one while preserving metadata?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting, select

I have a SQL database table that has four columns with different times. I want to be able to sort them in a way that I can merge each of a, b, c, and d timestamps into one column while preserving the id and metadata.

```
id | a_time | b_time | c_time | d_time | metadata1 | metadata2
1  | 8      | 7      | 2      | 4      | a         | b
2  | 6      | 1      | 12     | 10     | c         | d
3  | 5      | 9      | 3      | 11     | e         | f
```

In the above example, I would like something resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Do a triple UNION ALL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `union` between several queries on the different times:

```
(SELECT id, a_time AS time, metadata1, metadata2
 FROM   mytable)
UNION
(SELECT id, b_time AS time, metadata1, metadata2
 FROM   mytable)
UNION
(SELECT id, c_time AS time, metadata1, metadata2
 FROM   mytable)
UNION
(SELECT id, d_time AS time, metadata1, metadata2
 FROM   mytable)
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: "To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one." Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: Also, we should really not suggest a solution using Order by on column number. It is error prone.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to *unpivot* your data.  MySQL doesn't have much built in support for this, but an ANSI way to do this would be to use `UNION`:

```
SELECT id, a_time AS time, metadata1, metadata2 FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT id, b_time, metadata1, metadata2 FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT id, c_time, metadata1, metadata2 FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT id, d_time, metadata1, metadata2 FROM yourTable
ORDER BY time;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: "To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one." Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Your citation is referring to ordering _subqueries_ of a larger union query.  This has nothing to do with ordering an entire union query, which my answer is doing.

Comment: Please read "entire UNION result" - You may refer the link. For individual sub-select queries, there is a separate section

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya `A statement without parentheses is equivalent to one parenthesized as just shown.` ... I guess you forgot to read the rest of the article :-)

Comment: hmm :-| +1 but I prefer a clearer solution (parentheses help reader to understand the intent)

Comment: I agree about the readability.  The big issues here are 1) is what I wrote valid for MySQL, and 2) is what I wrote valid for ANSI SQL?  I can't remember having to wrap subqueries as you suggest on _any_ other database.  So, I would prefer to leave my answer as is.