# SQL is there a way to sort multiple time columns into one while preserving metadata without UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting, optimization

This is an extension to my previous question: [SQL is there a way to sort multiple time columns into one while preserving metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52982325/5422070)

I'm now trying to optimize this solution except now I have the case where the first timestamp column is SORTED. The problem with UNION as a solution is that it greatly increases the time to query for large sets of data because it actually places the data out of order again and requires another ORDER BY on the timestamp.

So, to summarize with the previous question:
I have a SQL database table that has four columns with different times **that is sorted on the first timestamp (a_time)**. I want to be able to sort them in a way that I can merge each of a, b, c, and d timestamps into one column while preserving the id and metadata.

```
id | a_time | b_time | c_time | d_time | metadata1 | metadata2
1  | 5      | 7      | 2      | 4      | a         | b
2  | 6      | 1      | 12     | 10     | c         | d
3  | 8      | 9      | 3      | 11     | e         | f
```

In the above example, I would like something resulting in:

```
id | time | metadata1 | metadata2
2  |  1   |     c     |    d
1  |  2   |     a     |    b
3  |  3   |     e     |    f
1  |  4   |     a     |    b
1  |  5   |     a     |    b
2  |  6   |     c     |    d
1  |  7   |     a     |    b
3  |  8   |     e     |    f
3  |  9   |     e     |    f
2  |  10  |     c     |    d
3  |  11  |     e     |    f
2  |  12  |     c     |    d
```

*I'm thinking that there isn't another way to do this and that I would probably need to parse through the query data differently, but I appreciate any insight to a possible optimized solution to this problem.*

Comment: there is a way to do this without unions. If you could add the schema of the tables (IOW, the create table statement) to your question, I'll create a SQLFiddle to show another way to do this.

Comment: See also `CASE ...` together with `GROU PBY id`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a numbers table, you can get your desired result by `JOIN`ing it to the metadata table:

```
SELECT m.id, n.n, m.metadata1, m.metadata2
FROM numbers n
JOIN metadata m ON m.a_time = n.n OR m.b_time = n.n OR m.c_time = n.n OR m.d_time = n.n
ORDER BY n.n
```

Output

```
id  n   metadata1   metadata2   
2   1   c           d
1   2   a           b
3   3   e           f
1   4   a           b
1   5   a           b
2   6   c           d
1   7   a           b
3   8   e           f
3   9   e           f
2   10  c           d
3   11  e           f
2   12  c           d
```

If you don't have a numbers table you can create one on the fly using this query:

```
SELECT m.id, n.n, m.metadata1, m.metadata2
FROM (SELECT n1.n + n10.n * 10 AS n 
      FROM (SELECT 0 AS n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) n1
           CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT 0 AS n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) n10
           ) n
JOIN metadata m ON m.a_time = n.n OR m.b_time = n.n OR m.c_time = n.n OR m.d_time = n.n
ORDER BY n.n
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9758c6/1)

**Update**

It seems for performance reasons it's better to add a `WHERE` clause that limits the range of numbers from the `numbers` table to the range of times in `metadata` i.e.

```
WHERE n.n <= (SELECT GREATEST(MAX(a_time), MAX(b_time), MAX(c_time), MAX(d_time)) FROM metadata)
```

Adding indexes to `a_time`, `b_time`, `c_time` and `d_time` also improves performance of this query.

Comment: Useful. I wanted to note that many of the DBAs I work with deliberately split queries that have OR conditions in up into separate queries that are later unioned together, because sqlserver won't necessarily use multiple indexes (e.g. Each _time column having its own index) in a single query that uses OR lookin for a single value across multiple columns, whereas it will if there are two queries that are unioned. As such this solution may ignore indexes on the time columns, which may make it go faster in certain contexts. Definitely one to perf test if required

Comment: @CaiusJard that's interesting. I tried adding indexes to each of the `*_time` columns in `metadata` and an `EXPLAIN` definitely suggested it was using them. I did see an improvement in execution time from 0.01 to 0.001 seconds as well.

Comment: The most memorable of these queries was a table describing conversations with a fromuser guid and a touser guid, several hundred million rows and two separate indexes; one for each userid column. `WHERE fromuser = @userid OR touser = @userid` was found to be far slower than `WHERE fromuser = @userid UNION WHERE touser = @userid` because only one of the indexes was used in the OR form. Perhaps there were other factors that were hindering some parallel aspect of the processing

Comment: @CaiusJard It's a good question. Perhaps query optimisation has just got a lot better in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `apply`:

```
select t.id, v.time, t.metadata1, t.metadata2
from t cross apply
     (values (a_time), (b_time), (c_time), (d_time)
     ) v(time)
order by v.time;
```